# Python - copy and paste values from a formula into another column (openpyxl or other libs)

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I am attempting to clean up an excel file and essentially what I want to do is this: I have inserted a formula in column B that references column A and would like to then take all the values in column B and paste special as values over column A. After, I would like to delete column B.

Does anyone know of anyway to do this via openpyxl library or another library?

Here is a copy of my code thus far:

```
import openpyxl as xl
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import os

def left(s, amount):
    return s[:amount]

def right(s, amount):
    return s[-amount:]

def mid(s, offset, amount):
    return s[offset:offset+amount]

filepath = r'...desktop\Scripts' + '\\'
filename = 'file.xlsx'

fn = filepath + filename

WB = xl.load_workbook(fn, data_only = True)

WS = WB.worksheets[1]

for i in sorted(WS.merged_cell_ranges):
    WS.unmerge_cells(str(i))


WB.save(filepath + 'unmerged.xlsx')

unmerged = pd.read_excel(filepath + 'unmerged.xlsx', sheetname = 1)

unmerged.insert(1, 'ifIsBlank', '')
unmerged.insert(5, 'trimSubst', '')

inserted = unmerged.to_excel(filepath + 'inserted.xlsx', index = False)

WB = xl.load_workbook(filepath + 'inserted.xlsx')

WS = WB.worksheets[0]

WS['A'][0].value = 'BU'
WS['E'][0].value = 'em name' 


blankCount1 = 1
blankCount2 = 0
trimCount = 1
for i, cell in enumerate(WS['B']):        
    cell.value = '=IF(ISBLANK(A' + str(blankCount1) + '), B' + str(blankCount2) + ', A' + str(blankCount1) + ')'.format(i)
    blankCount1 += 1
    blankCount2 += 1

for j, cell in enumerate(WS['F']):        
    cell.value = '=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(E' + str(trimCount) + ', "~", "_"))'.format(j)
    trimCount += 1

WS['B'][0].value = 'Category Name'
WS['F'][0].value = 'Item Name'



WB.save(filepath + 'formula.xlsx')
valWB = xl.load_workbook(filepath + 'formula.xlsx', data_only = True)
```

So the issue I'm running into is that when I read formula.xlsx as a .csv (desired file type of my final output), it shows nothing in the cells that have the formula- Is there a way to essentially copy and paste the values that come out of the formula into another column?

Thanks!

Comment: So you're opening an Excel file in Python, generating a string, putting that string in the Python object, saving it as an Excel file so that the string will be interpreted as an Excel command, then opening the Excel file again? Why not just write your clean-up function in Python, instead of trying to create Excel commands in Python?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I actually recently picked up python as a means to try and automate some tasks and so my conceptual knowledge isn't quite good-

So the easiest thing for me was to mimic what I had been doing manually :/

Comment: You can't use openpyxl to evaluate Excel formulae. You must do this using Excel or OpenOffice or something similar.